# Elasticsearch: How to get all documents when array in terms query is empty

Tags: elasticsearch

I´m filtering my documents in ES for a specific field (id) which has multiple variables [abc,xyz]. These variables are given through an user input in another service. I built a query with filter terms and an array for the input. It works so far but I would like to get all documents when the array is empty. I´m not sure how to solve this exactly.

````
{
                "nested": {
                    "query": {
                        "bool":{
                            "must": {
                                "match_all": {}
                                },
                                    "filter": [
                                        {
                                        "terms": {
                                        "products.id": ["abc","xyz"] 
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    },
                                     "path": "products",
                                     "ignore_unmapped": false,
                                     "score_mode": "none",
                                     "boost": 1.0
                                }
                            },```
````

Comment: if I understand your question correctly, the requirement is that you want to get the documents of those ids that are included in `products.id`, and if nothing is there in `products.id` you want to return all the documents. Correct ?

Comment: Yes, you're right

Comment: Will the `products.id` field exist and be empty? or do you want to query docs that don't have this field at all?

Comment: Products.id is a field in the docs which is never empty and exits everytime. I want to use this query for users to search for a spefic product, but if they don't insert an id  in "terms": "products.id": [] I would like to get all docs. So basically return all without filtering.

Answer (score 1):

I´ve got a solution with the help of velocity. It´s a simple if loop. And the query will only be wirtten/executed if there are entries in the array. But thank you all for your help!

```
#if(${productIdent})
                {
                "nested": {
                    "query": {
                        "bool":{
                        "must": {
                            "match_all": {}
                                },
                                    "filter": [
                                        {
                                        "terms": {
                                        "products.id": [${productIdent}]
                                                }
                                            }
                                        ]
                                        }
                                    },
                                     "path": "products",
                                     "ignore_unmapped": false,
                                     "score_mode": "none",
                                     "boost": 1.0
                                }
                            },
                            #else #end
```